# How to register cell for a few UITableViews, while every table is in the same UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

I created `UITableViewController` with some cells. Inside some of those cells, there are another UITableViews with cells with the same layout. How to register cell in way to make it visible for table in another global UITableView:

- UITableViewController:

  - UITableView main

    - UITableViewCell identifier1

      - UITableView2

        - **UITableViewCell identifier3**
    - UITableViewCell identifier2

      - UITableView3

        - **UITableViewCell identifier3**

All I need is to prevent create layout of cell in every subtable `UITableView` main. I would like to register cell in one cell, and use it in every another UITableView in this controller.

Comment: putting multiple `UITableView`s into one `UITableViewController` doesnt seem like a perfect design choice... are you sure you need to use this setup and can't approach your problem e.g. by using multiple sections?

Comment: If I have understood it right, you want to reuse cells and share them between all the `UITableView`s you have?

Comment: I agree with @nburk. It sounds like a bad idea to have such hierarchy. Why did you choose to do it this way?

Comment: No, because in my `UITableViewController` there is 6 static cells. 2 of them have UITableView inside. In those tables i need use cells with the same layout